# How to send MySQL query results to outfile and standard output at the same time?

Tags: mysql, php

I "normally" query MySQL with

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM tablename LIMIT 10;
```

and sometimes instead send the output to a file with

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM tablename LIMIT 10 INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/outfile';
```

Is there a way to do both with one query?  I am trying to store a dump file of the query results while still manipulating the output (in PHP).

Comment: Where do you "write" the query, on PHP code? If so, which connector are you using/how are you doing it? Because in most cases, the own connector has the tools to perform what you want.

Comment: I am querying with PDO and can write the file using PHP and `fetchAll()` function, but would like to know if it's possible to do this from the MySQL query.

Comment: You cannot "call" PHP from MySQL. But you can access that file from PHP with standard I/O calls.

Comment: If you want to do this with ALL statements on a given connection, you could invoke mysql with `tee` to begin with, as seen [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-commands.html).